# libxml2/tree.h not found in Xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, xcode6.1, ios8.1

Hi in my Xcode project I have added libxml2.dylib framework.I am getting a error:
libxml2/tree.h not found.

I have set Header Search Path is "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" and i have tried other ways which i was found in googling but am getting still error.

How to resolve this issue? I am using Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Please add into your question exactly what your include statement looks like.